# Exporting SQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpMyAdmin, there is an option to export the entire table (or database) into a .SQL file.

I cannot work out how they do this - as I want to stick it into a CRON job to make daily and weekly backups of databases.  But there doesn't seem to be any single command that does it - is there?

Comment: I think this is done by calling [`mysqldump`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) with the right parameters.

Comment: http://dbperf.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/automate-mysql-dumps-using-linux-cron-job/ Will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use mysqldump

```
  mysqldump -h hostname -u user -pPassword dbname >/path/to/file
```

host is optional if host is localhost. depending on some settings user and password may be optional as well. Note you may want to add the date name

```
  mysqldump -h hostname -u root mydb > /path/to/backup/$(date +%a)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can run these commands with PHP, copy the following piece of code into a file and execute it with cron job.

```
<?php

//Backup:

//ENTER THE RELEVANT INFO BELOW
$mysqlDatabaseName ='databasename';
$mysqlUserName ='username';
$mysqlPassword ='password';
$mysqlHostName ='localhost';
//$mysqlExportPath ='database.sql';

$mysqlImportFilename ='myownsit_obsolcms.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysql -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' < ' .$mysqlImportFilename;
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        echo 'Import file <b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b> successfully imported to database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was an error during import. Please make sure the import file is saved in the same folder as this script and check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Import Filename:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlImportFilename .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}



//Restore:
$mysqlExportPath ='path_to_file/database.sql';

//DONT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE
//Export the database and output the status to the page
$command='mysqldump --opt -h' .$mysqlHostName .' -u' .$mysqlUserName .' -p' .$mysqlPassword .' ' .$mysqlDatabaseName .' admin contents categires google_map cms_labels news pages page_contents partners photos plugins products social testimonials themes users youtube> ~/' .$mysqlExportPath;
//$command = "$ mysqldump -u $mysqlUserName -p $mysqlPassword $mysqlDatabaseName > myownsit_obsolcms.sql";
exec($command,$output=array(),$worked);
switch($worked){
    case 0:
        //echo 'Database <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> successfully exported to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 1:
        echo 'There was a warning during the export of <b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b> to <b>~/' .$mysqlExportPath .'</b>';
        break;
    case 2:
        echo 'There was an error during export. Please check your values:<br/><br/><table><tr><td>MySQL Database Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlDatabaseName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL User Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlUserName .'</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Password:</td><td><b>NOTSHOWN</b></td></tr><tr><td>MySQL Host Name:</td><td><b>' .$mysqlHostName .'</b></td></tr></table>';
        break;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, mysqldump: http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/mysqldump1.html

You'll need to have server access to use it though.  Also, if you're feeling adventurous and want to maintain consistent backups look up information on master/slave setups.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shell script and call that script via cron job. 
See this Working [Example](http://blog.sleeplessbeastie.eu/2012/11/22/simple-shell-script-to-backup-mysql-databases/)